# Copy a directory recursively from perforce server to local machine (without creating working space) using perforce command?

Tags: recursion, directory, copy, perforce, workspace

I am able to copy a file from remote Perforce server to my local machine using this command

```
p4 print -o <output_filename> <remote_filename>
```

However, I have two issues here.
First, I have to manually specify my output filename.
Second, I cannot print out all files and sub-directories within a directory.

What I want to do is coping a specific directory recursively from Perforce server to my local machine directory without creating a workspace on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy answer:** Discard the requirement to not create a workspace on your local machine, and create a workspace on your local machine.  It is **way easier and faster** to create a workspace, `sync -p`, and delete the workspace than it is to re-implement `p4 sync`.

```
p4 --field "View=//depot/path/... //TEMPCLIENT/..." --field "Root=C:\output_path" client -o TEMPCLIENT | p4 client -i
p4 -c TEMPCLIENT sync -p
p4 client -d TEMPCLIENT
```

**Hard answer:** Implement your own view mapping logic.  Use `p4 files //depot/path/...` to get the list of files, then use a regex to map each depot file into a local file, then run a `p4 print` command for each pair.  It'd look something like:

```
p4 -F %depotFile% files //depot/path/... | (some gnarly piece of awk/sed/perl that takes "depotFile" as input and produces "print -o localFile depotFile" as output) | p4 -x - run
```

Comment: So I follow Sam Stafford hard answer by listing each file's full path in a desired directory I want to copy. Then I code a script to substring of each file's path to get the filename. Finally, I ran "print" command for each file. It's similar to regex.